# The name of 16 and 32 bits

Tags: terminology, conventions, bit

8 bits is called "byte". How is 16 bits called? "Short"? "Word"?

And what about 32 bits? I know "int" is CPU-dependent, I'm interested in universally applicable names.

Comment: *I'm interested in universally applicable names.*  Then the universally applicable names you should use are "16-bits" and "32-bits".  If your universally applicable names context precludes **byte** specifically for 8-bits, you can use "8-bits" or "octet".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A *byte* is the smallest unit of data that a computer can work with. The C language defines `char` to be one "byte" and has `CHAR_BIT` bits. On most systems this is 8 bits.

A *word* on the other hand, is usually the size of values typically handled by the CPU.  Most of the time, this is the size of the general-purpose registers. The problem with this definition, is it doesn't age well.

For example, the MS Windows `WORD` datatype was defined back in the early days, when 16-bit CPUs were the norm. When 32-bit CPUs came around, the definition stayed, and a 32-bit integer became a `DWORD`. And now we have 64-bit `QWORD`s.

Far from "universal", but here are several different takes on the matter:

[**Windows**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- `BYTE` - 8 bits, unsigned
- `WORD` - 16 bits, unsigned
- `DWORD` - 32 bits, unsigned
- `QWORD` - 64 bits, unsigned

[**GDB**](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html):

- Byte
- Halfword (two bytes).
- Word (four bytes).
- Giant words (eight bytes).

[**`<stdint.h>`**](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/7posix/stdint.h/):

- `uint8_t` - 8 bits, unsigned
- `uint16_t` - 16 bits, unsigned
- `uint32_t` - 32 bits, unsigned
- `uint64_t` - 64 bits, unsigned
- `uintptr_t` - pointer-sized integer, unsigned

(Signed types exist as well.)

If you're trying to write portable code that relies upon the size of a particular data type (e.g. you're implementing a network protocol), **always** use `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: Spot On. These terms are extremely importand when dealing with Computer Architecture & Assembly Language (low level Programming).

Answer (score 4):

The correct name for a group of exactly 8 bits is really an [octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_%28computing%29). A [byte](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) may have more than or fewer than 8 bits (although this is relatively rare).

Beyond this there are no rigorously well-defined terms for 16 bits, 32 bits, etc, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

There's no universal name for 16-bit or 32-bit units of measurement.

The term 'word' is used to describe the number of bits processed at a time by a program or operating system. So, in a 16-bit CPU, the word length is 16 bits. In a 32-bit CPU, the word length is 32 bits. I also believe the term is a little flexible, so if I write a program that does all its processing in chunks of say, 10 bits, I could refer to those 10-bit chunks as 'words'.

And just to be clear; 'int' is not a unit of measurement for computer memory. It really is just the data type used to store integer numbers (i.e. numbers with a decimal component of zero). So if you find a way to implement integers using only 2 bits (or whatever) in your programming language, that would still be an int.

Answer (score 3):

Dr. Werner Buchholz coined the word byte to mean, "a unit of digital information to describe an ordered group of bits, as the smallest amount of data that a computer could process." Therefore, the word's actual meaning is dependent on the machine in question's architecture. The number of bits in a byte is therefore arbitrary, and could be 8, 16, or even 32.

For a thorough dissertation on the subject, refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte).

Comment: As the Wikipedia article says, the de facto modern usage is that a "byte" is always 8 bits (even for machines that use 32- or 64-bit words). Other definitions of byte did float around in the early days of computing, but those are effectively archaic usages now.

Comment: @Luke I wouldn't say "archaic"; there are DSP chips where `CHAR_BIT` is 16 or 32: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091992/is-char-bit-ever-8

Answer (score 1):

`short`, `word` and `int` are all dependent on the compiler and/or architecture.

- `int` is a datatype and is **usually** 32-bit on desktop 32-bit or 64-bit systems. I don't think it's ever larger than the register size of the underlying hardware, so it should always be a fast (and usually large enough) datatype for common uses.
- `short` **may** be of smaller size then `int`, that's all you know. In practice, they're **usually** 16-bit, but you cannot depend on it.
- `word` is not a datatype, it rather denotes the natural register size of the underlying hardware.

And regarding the names of 16 or 32 bits, there aren't any. There is no reason to label them.

Comment: From C89, `int` has been required to be at least 16 bits (by the "at least" requirements on INT_MIN and INT_MAX). So on a sub-16-bit CPU, `int` will be larger than the registers. (At least, it will in strict-ANSI mode...)

Answer (score 1):

(Nigh 11 years later...)

WikiPedia offers several names on their [Units of Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information) page, including "doublet" and "chomp" for 16-bit quantities, and "quadlet" and "octlet" for 32- and 64-bit quantities.

Of note, many of these terms are cited to be from either manufacturers' documentation or from standards organizations (such as "IEEE Standard for a 32-bit Microprocessor Architecture", which defines doublets, quadlets, octlets, and hexlets).

Also of note, some of these terms are specified in terms of *bytes* rather than bits, so they are still technically imprecise, as multiple other answers have cautioned about.

I particularly liked the "sniff," the "snort," and the "tribble" for 1-, 2-, and 3-bit elements. I'll have to make an effort to work those into my conversations...

Answer (score 0):

I used to ear them referred as byte, word and long word. But as others mention it is dependant on the native architecture you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

They are called 2 bytes and 4 bytes

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any universal terms for 16 and 32 bits. The size of a word is machine dependent.