# Is CHAR_BIT ever > 8?

Tags: c, char, byte, bit

The ISO C Standard requires `CHAR_BIT` to be at least 8.

With POSIX mandating `CHAR_BIT` be equal to 8, and (almost?) all networking and communication standards using *octets*, is there *any* contemporary C implementation where `CHAR_BIT` > 8?

(Note: I'm not interested in historic computer architectures using 18 or 36 bit words. It's genuinely a question about C as it is used today on current hardware; think systems with a C99 or later implementation).

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char

Comment: IIRC there are DSP chips with 16 bit chars.

Comment: the wide characters, used in several language alphabets is usually 16 bits

Comment: Yes.  Old Cray machines had the equivalent of `CHAR_BIT == 32` (so `sizeof(int) == 1 == sizeof(short) == sizeof(char)`.  Modern DSP systems can have `CHAR_BIT == 16`.

Comment: The TI compiler for the TMS320C54x (commonly known as the C54x) defines `CHAR_BIT` as 16. See Table 7.1 in the User's Guide: http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ug/spru103g/spru103g.pdf

Comment: It would be interesting to see if there are non-DSP implementations where `CHAR_BIT > 8`.

Comment: The XAP processor created by Cambridge Consultants and powering a few billion Bluetooth headsets around the world have CHAR_BIT == 16

Comment: @ChrisStJohn You should post an answer with a link to the official documentation specifying CHAR_BIT.

Comment: Possibly also related to: [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708810/fixed-char-bit-on-various-systems).

Comment: Also see [Exotic architectures the standards committees care about](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6971886/1708801)

Comment: Related: [Are there machines, where sizeof(char) != 1, or at least CHAR_BIT > 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215445/12149471)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[TMS320C28x](https://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/microcontrollers_16-bit_32-bit/c2000_performance/control_automation/f28m3x/overview.page) DSP from Texas Instruments has a byte with 16 bits.

[Documentation](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=spru514&fileType=pdf) for the compiler specifies `CHAR_BIT` as 16 on page 101.

This appears to be a modern processor (currently being sold), compilers supporting C99 and C++03.

Comment: Two outstanding answers making it hard to select a bounty winner. So I rolled a dice... one of you gets the "accept" score, the other the bounty.

Answer (score 27):

Another example is Analog Devices' [SHARC processor family](http://www.analog.com/en/products/processors-dsp/sharc.html). 
Its C implementation, [CrossCore Embedded Studio](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/processors-and-dsp/evaluation-and-development-software/adswt-cces.html), has `CHAR_BIT == 32` and [claims](http://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/software-manuals/cces-SharcCompiler-manual.pdf) to provide freestanding C99 and C++11 conformance.

Comment: Curious, is a `char` a signed char or an unsigned one there?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica signed. Search for `"plain" char` in the document.

Comment: [Compiler Manual for SHARC
Processors](http://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/software-manuals/cces-SharcCompiler-manual.pdf) has  "A "plain" char has the same range and value as a signed char." .  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Analog Devices' SHARC DSP was already mentioned (CHAR_BIT==32).  Let me add that recent **SHARC+** cores (I use ADSP-SC589 and CCES toolchain) can run apps written in two modes: **CHAR_BIT == 8** or **CHAR_BIT == 32**.  You can even **mix'n'match** the two modes together in one app.  Although I would not recommend this for development in general, I find it useful when porting code.