# Are there platforms where the size of shorts is actually larger than 16bits

Tags: c

As far as I know the standard says that the size of the `short` type must be at least 16 bits.

Now I'm wondering if there are actually platforms where `short`s are 32 bit or even larger.

I'm aware of `stddef.h` and that the types defined there should be used if a certain size is required.

Comment: @EOF related, but not a duplicate.

Comment: @FelixPalmen The bounty'd answer provides an example of an architecture where `CHAR_BIT == 32`. Given that `short` cannot be smaller than `char`, it follows that `short` is 32-bit or larger.

Comment: @EOF for a duplicate, it's not enough that an answer also answers this question "by accident" -- it must basically ask the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can find [an example here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) (well, not 32 bit, but "larger than 16"). The example given there is the [UNICOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNICOS) operating system for "Cray" supercomputers, which has 64bit `short`.

Comment: OK, thanks. So I suppose shorts > 16 bits are still rather exotic.

Comment: @MichaelWalz indeed, but what do you do with this information? If it's possible, portable code must be prepared for it ;)

Comment: It's more of curiosity.

Comment: 32-bit short may exist [even on modern DSPs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38360262/995714)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC some exotic implementation of C99 above (in/for) Common Lisp (or perhaps only SBCL) has been coded with all of `char`, `short`, `int` being 32 bits exactly.

But I could be wrong.