# What type sizes in C are going to be constant on any given platform?

Tags: c, types, cross-platform, sizeof

In C, is it safe to assume that `sizeof(short)` will be 2, or `sizeof(int)` will be 4 on any given platform, for example? Even if those are consistant, are there any volatile type sizes, for example `sizeof(long double)` might be 16 vary in size? Which types are safe to assume that their size is constant? I know `char` is one of them `sizeof(char)` is always 1, but any other constant ones?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor/2331835#2331835

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor)

Answer (score 4):

For fixed-size integers, like `int64_t` you can be sure that the size is `64 / CHAR_BIT`. You can be sure that `sizeof(char)` is 1. Pretty much everything else has a minimum size, not an exact size.

Do note that `CHAR_BIT` is not fixed. It has a minimum size of 8. See [Is CHAR_BIT ever > 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32091992/10147399)

Comment: `sizeof(int64_t)` may be less than eight. The “size” of an object in C is the number of bytes it requires, but a byte may be more than eight bits in a C implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Why would a byte ever be something other than 8 bits?

Comment: @user226527 there are systems with bytes larger than 8. A byte is really the size of `char`.

Comment: @user226527: Because C was designed to be a portable language in the sense that compilers and execution environments for it could be provided on a great variety of hardware, including hardware that used different word sizes. There is nothing in the laws of physics that requires bytes to be eight bits and, as computers were being developed, a great variety of designs were tried.

Answer (score 3):

The size of `int` will be compiler dependent. Now a days, on most systems, you will find `sizeof(int)` to be 4. Earlier when processors were 16 bit, an int was 2 bytes. But now-a-days, 4 will be common for `int` and 8 bytes for `long int`.

---

The  C standards say nothing regarding the exact size of any integer types aside from `char`. A `long` may be 4 bytes on 32-bits system and 8 bytes on 64-bits  systems. The standard, however does specify the minimum size that a data-type must be of.

C standard only requires the following points about the sizes of types

- `sizeof(char)` == 1
- `CHAR_BIT` >= 8
- `short` and `int` >= 16 bits,
- `long` >= 32 bits,
- `long long` (since C99) >= 64 bits
- `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`

> **Note :** The sizes are inferred from the range of each data-type. C standard doesn't explicitly even mention sizes. It mentions only the
> range as -
>
> - `char` : -127 to 127
> - `unsigned char` : 0 to 255
> - `short` : -32767 to 32767
> - `unsigned short` : 0 to 65535
> - `int` : -32767 to 32767
> - `unsigned int` : 0 to 65535
> - `long` : -2147483647 to 2147483647
> - `unsigned long` : 0 to 4294967295
> - `long long` : -9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775807
> - `unsigned long long` : 0 to 18446744073709551615

---

The rest is implementation dependent. Compilers are free to allocate more memory than is specified in the standard. So, in most modern systems, you will find that `int` will be 32 bits, `long` would be `64` bits and `long double` would be 16 bytes. Again, these values could vary, but I mentioned these because they are common values that you would see on a modern machine.

Here's a table from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) which gives more information on this -

[image]

For floating point numbers, C or C++ doesn't specify anything. There is a standard (IEEE754): floats are 32 bit and doubles are 64. This is a hardware standard, not a C standard.

Comment: How about short? Are there any minimum sizes for short?

Comment: @user226527 A `short` must be atleast 16 bits in size which is same as that for `int`

Comment: Do note that the C standard explicitly specifies ranges, not sizes in bits.

Comment: @＿Static＿assert That's correct . But we could infer the sizes in bits from their range

Comment: @Abhishek sure. Just wanted to add that comment for future readers :)

Comment: @Abhishek: I took the liberty to fix some typos. Your answer is quite precise and thorough, but the C Standard does specify quite a bit (!) about floating point types, although not as much as IEEE-754.

Comment: @Abhishek: Does the C Standard imply that `sizeof(float) <= sizeof(double) <= sizeof(long double)` ?

Comment: @chqrlie > There are three real floating types, designated as float, double, and long
double. The set of values of the type float is a subset of the set of values of the
type double; the set of values of the type double is a subset of the set of values of the
type long double. That's all I found. It didn't specify anything regarding the sizes of float types

Answer (score 1):

any size variable can be volatile

example:

```
volatile double x[1000000];
```

> In C, is it safe to assume that sizeof(short) will be 2, or
> sizeof(int) will be 4 on any given platform, for example?

No it is not safe.  If you want to have fixed size integers use typed from the `stdint.h` header - for example `int16_t` - signed integer 16 bits/.

Comment: That's not really what I meant, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: That is not the meaning of “volatile” the question is asking about.

Comment: It does not appear that the OP is referring to the `volatile` keyword, but rather the notion that datatype sizes can vary between implementations.