# Store numerical values in char variables in C++?

Tags: c++

Is there any practical situation when we should store numerical values in char type variables in C++?

Comment: If you need a variable that's a single byte, then yes. Remember, `char`s are `int`s, just with a smaller range.

Comment: Are you talking about char or a c-string? Many people new to the language (who are being taught c with classes instead of  modern c++ which has std::string) mistakenly say char when they mean a c-string.

Comment: Sure, why not ? 8 bit audio samples, pixel component values, H/W register values - there are many things that have a <= 8 bit range.

Comment: @PaulR Those typically use either `unsigned char` or `signed char`. Why use `char` for those over the others?

Comment: When there's an existing library or platform interface that uses `char` and we want to match it?

Comment: @eerorika: yes, I was assuming the OP was referring to types which are of width char, but the question is rather vague and lacking in detail. Ideally of course you would use `uint8_t` *et al*.

Comment: fwiw, `char` always store numerical values. Assuming ascii encoding, there is literally no difference between storing an `'A'` or storing `65` in a `char`

Answer (score 5):

If you need lots of integers each of which would fit into a byte, and you're constrained in memory, you can use `signed char` or `unsigned char` to store them. Whether or not plain `char` is signed depends on the implementation, so you'll want to avoid that. To be more expressive, you can use `int8_t` and `uint8_t` which are defined in `<cstdint>` (and `<stdint.h>` though it's deprecated). Those are usually just a typedef for `signed char` and `unsigned char` anyway, so be careful when printing their numeric values.

Comment: Note, however, that `int8_t` and `uint8_t` will not exist on a system that does not have an 8-bit integer type, so use of these types should be reserved for programs that require **exactly** 8 bits. `int_least8_t` and `uint_least8_t` are a better choice if the goal is just to minimize memory usage.

Comment: @PeteBecker that's correct. Related: [Is CHAR_BIT ever > 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32091992/10147399)

Comment: Yes, `CHAR_BIT` is greater than 8 for some hardware. I don't remember what it was, but there was a line of mainframes with 36-bit registers, and they could be sub-divided into 9-bit registers, so `char` was naturally 9 bits wide. These days, some DSP chips don't have anything smaller than 32 bits, so `char` is 32 bits wide.