# Why does the following programme gives output as "-128" despite its value assigned as "128"?

Tags: c, char, signed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    signed char chr=128;

    printf("%d\n",chr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `128` is out of the range of an 8-bit `signed char`. What result did you expect?

Comment: @WeatherVane Please give some more light on the explaination. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know about integer limits? A `char` value takes up 1 byte. A byte is usually 8 bits. To calculate the limit through the number of bits, the calculation is `2^n-1` meaning an integer with 8 bits has a range from 0 to 255 when unsigned. Since your variable is signed, it allocates a bit to the sign, meaning it has a range from -128 to 127. Since you assigned it as 128, it overflowed, rolling back over to -128. If your program doesn't use negative numbers, you should use `signed char`, otherwise you might want to use a `short` which is 2 bytes.

Comment: That was a viable explaination. Thanks Sir.

Comment: The C standard does not fix the number of bits in a byte. It must be at least eight but may be larger.

Comment: When addressing integer “overflows,” care should be taken with C semantics. This is not an overflow as the C standard defines it, and the standard does not require “rolling back over.” Conversion of out-of-range integer values to signed integer types is implementation-defined. The implementation may define it to wrap, to clamp, to trap, or to do other things.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the error however seems to be an 8 bits byte overflow. There might be embedded processors and mini/mainframes with more than 8 bits per "byte," can you mention one? (interested)

Comment: @JoopEggen Do you mean like [those ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091992/is-char-bit-ever-8)?

Comment: Re "*A `char` value takes up 1 byte.*", Yes. /// Re "*A byte is 8 bits*", Usually, but not always. They have been known to be as large as 32 bits, and as odd as 9 bits. That said, it is 8 bits in the OP's case. /// Re "*Since your variable is signed, it has a range from -128 to 127.*", Or -127 to 127 on some systems. That said, it's obviously -128 to 127 for the OP. ///  Re "*rolling back over to -128.*", That is what happpened, but other implementations may handle it differently.